# Recursively parse an object containing children to a key-value format object

Tags: javascript, recursion

Considering i got an object like this:

```js
const o = {
  name: 'name1',
  age: 1,
  children: [{
    name: 'name21',
    age: 21,
    children: [{
      name: 'name31',
      age: 31,
      children: []
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'name22',
    age: 22,
    children: []
  }]
}
```

It has three properties, the children property could be an empty array representing it has no child. I want to transform this object to the following format:

```js
const newObject = {
  name1_1: {
    name21_21: {
      name31_31: {}
    }, 
    name22_22: {}
  }
}
```

The key will be the format of `name_key`, and the value will be its related children, if the object has no children, the value will just be an empty object.

Here is my implementation:

```js
const o = {
  name: 'name1',
  age: 1,
  children: [{
    name: 'name21',
    age: 21,
    children: [{
      name: 'name31',
      age: 31,
      children: []
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'name22',
    age: 22,
    children: []
  }]
}

const parser = obj => {
  const result = {}
  const { name, age } = obj
  const key = `${name}_${age}`
  if (obj.children.length > 0) {
    obj.children.forEach(child => {
      result[key] = parser(child)
    })
  } else {
    result[key] = {}
  }
  return result
}

console.log(parser(o)) // { "name1_1": { "name22_22": {} } }
```

I am not sure what i did wrong here, can someone help me a little bit please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you implementation, `result[key] = parser(child)` overrides the object in second iteration to set `result[key] = { name22_22: {} }`. So the fix is to extend the `result[key]` object instead of reassignment.

```js
const o = {
  name: 'name1',
  age: 1,
  children: [{
    name: 'name21',
    age: 21,
    children: [{
      name: 'name31',
      age: 31,
      children: []
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'name22',
    age: 22,
    children: []
  }]
}

const parser = obj => {
  const result = {}
  const {
    name,
    age
  } = obj
  const key = `${name}_${age}`
  if (obj.children.length > 0) {
    obj.children.forEach(child => {
    //  result[key] = parser(child);
      result[key] = {
        ...result[key],
        ...parser(child),
      }
    })
  } else {
    result[key] = {}
  }
  return result
}
console.log(parser(o)) // {name1_1: {name21_21: {name31_31: {}}, name22_22: {}}}
```

Comment: Cool bro, appreciate that, your explanation is super helpful!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign the result of recursive calls of you function to the current object but before that you should also initialize that object if it doesn't exist.

```js
const o = {"name":"name1","age":1,"children":[{"name":"name21","age":21,"children":[{"name":"name31","age":31,"children":[]}]},{"name":"name22","age":22,"children":[]}]}

const parser = ({ name, age, children }) => {
  const result = {}
  const key = `${name}_${age}`;

  if (!result[key]) result[key] = {}
  if (children.length) {
    children.forEach(child => {
      Object.assign(result[key], parser(child))
    })
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(parser(o))
```

Comment: Cheers, bro. So what i did wrong is i used `result[key] = parser(child)`, and in this way `result` will be overlapped each time by the new parser(child) result. You use `Object.assign` so that you are mutating the result rather than overlapping it directly. Is my understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes and also here I always check if there is `result[key]` before and if there isn't then I set its value to empty object.

Answer (score 1):

There's already a good answer explaining what you did wrong and how to fix it.  But I think you're working too hard here.  Let the recursion do the heavy-lifting, and use `Object.assign` to glue things together.  That allows for as simple an implementation as this:

```js
const parser = ({name, age, children}) =>
  ({[`${name}_${age}`]: Object .assign ({}, ... (children || []) .map (parser))})

const o = {name: 'name1', age: 1, children: [{name: 'name21', age: 21, children: [{name: 'name31', age: 31, children: []}]}, {name: 'name22', age: 22, children: []}]}

console .log (parser (o))
```

Comment: pop, pop, bang!